# How to set opacity of imageview in android from transparency 0% to 100%?

Tags: android, splash-screen

My purpose to use opacity with Image view because i put it in splash screen. I want the imageview start up from opacity 0 to 100 percents.

```
    imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imvLogo);

    for (int i=1;i<11;i++){

        for (int j=1;j<1000;j++){
        }
        imageView.getBackground().setAlpha(10*i);
    }
```

i think the opacity will increase more and more by for loop but the result not like i think. so anyone have any idea?
sorry if this question doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1):

try this solution,

You can call the animation from you activity like this,

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Animation loadAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
loadAnimation.setDuration(2000);
imageView.startAnimation(loadAnimation);
```

Comment: oh wow. it saves my night. The best answer that i have researched. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Another nice way is as follows.

Set the `alpha` to 0 in your xml and then in the code do this:

```
imageView.animate().alpha(1);
```